# wuic javascript optimization version number calculation

Tags: javascript, java, css, optimization, minify

Using http://wuic.github.io/, i noticed that the version number of the js files is not the same in different envrionments (*different developpers envrionments for example*).
Is there a way that this version number does not depend on the environment ?

**It's important** because in our clustered environment, js resources **can be served by any cluster nodes**, so if a html is served by one node and the version number of the resource number in it is node dependant, **it's problematic** ...

Answer (score 0):

By default WUIC computes the version number from a file thanks to its last modification date on the current file system. If your build process touch the file, the date will change even if the content is not modified.

To avoid this problem, you can add `c.g.wuic.dao.contentBasedVersionNumber=true` to your `wuic.properties` files. WUIC will computes a checksum by reading the content, and the version number will be the same for any build.